# Negative Slicing Step in Python Not getting Output

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and have a problem with Negative Slicing step. So can anyone explain me Negative Slicing Step and my question is why the below code behaving like this,

```
var1='1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i'
print('1st result',var1[-2:-10:-1]) #Get output
print('2nd result',var1[-2:-10:1])  #No Output
print('3rd result',var1[2:10:-1])   #No Output
```

Comment: There are no numbers in the directed range from 2 to 10 with a difference of -1.

Comment: Do you *actually* get no output at all, or just ``2nd result `` and ``3rd result ``?

Answer (score 0):

Negative slicing is not but positive slicing with step -1.

> slice = slice[start,end,step]

You're not able to get output for `print('2nd result',var1[-2:-10:1])  #No Output`  because step of 1 will make index instance as -1 from -2, which is out the prescribed range.

The same is true for `print('3rd result',var1[2:10:-1])   #No Output`

You should instead be doing

```
print('2nd result',var1[-2:-10:-1])
print('3rd result',var1[2:10][::-1])
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this you could also write:
print("result",var1 [2:10] + var1[-1]), and same for 3rd result
And if you still want to use that way, you could also write down the output.

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant. The question is specifically about negative step. Offering a different approach is really off-topic here...